# how to get onTouch part of the image on imageview's canvas, and display that portion in its magnified form in the same canvas

Tags: android, android-canvas

I have a custom ImageView which allows zoom, pan, drawing lines,rect etc. Say a line is drawn on the image. Now, what i want is, when the user touches that line to move it, a magnified image of that portion should be displayed somewhere on top right corner of the imageview(i.e., within canvas) which allows user to place the line accurately.The magnified image portion should contain the line as well and it should keep updating the image as user moves the line.

I've tried using shaders

```
mShader = new BitmapShader(myBitmap, TileMode.CLAMP, TileMode.CLAMP);
    shademat=new Matrix();
    mPaint = new Paint();
    mPaint.setShader(mShader);
```

and in ACTION_DOWN event, I have

```
 shademat.reset();
 shademat.postScale(2f, 2f, curr.x, curr.y);
 prex=curr.x;
 prey=curr.y;
```

and in onDraw()

```
 mShader.setLocalMatrix(shademat);   
 canvas.drawCircle(prex, prey, 100, mPaint);
```

But I am not able to get the canvas image onto shader, b'coz somehow

```
canvas.setBitmap(myBitmap)
```

gives error on ICS even after disabling "Force GPU rendering" by

```
android:hardwareAccelerated="false"
```

Also I'm not finding a way to get the image part to be displayed on top right corner of the canvas.
Is there any other way to get image from canvas to bitmap? please help.

Comment: Did you solve your problem? I need to do the same thing...